# Fitting distributions

Tags: distributions, modeling, gamma-distribution, risk

I have some data on serving sizes of a particular food (raw oysters), and I am trying to determine what probability distribution I should select to model these data for a risk assessment (RA). The R package I am planning to use for the RA (mc2d) uses a gamma distribution for serving size in its example, although the package allows you to pick pretty much any distribution you need.

I am used to selecting distributions largely based upon the nature of the data. For instance, since I have worked often with ecological community data, I have used the Poisson distribution for rare occurrence events (finding an animal). However, in this case I can't seem to find what people generally use for serving sizes.

Does it matter what distribution you use as long as it fits your data? Eyeballing it, the gamma distribution looks like it will fit pretty well if a = 1. But I don't really understand the gamma distribution despite reading about it, and can't piece together in what situations it is used. It actually seems as if the only thing that matters about the gamma distribution is that you select the two parameters to model the shape correctly. Furthermore, I imagine there are other distributions with other set parameters that would fit these data similarly, and it makes me uncomfortable not knowing the difference between them.

Edit: for instance, the Erlang distribution also looks very similar to what I need at k=1. How does one decide between two such as these?

Comment: The Erlang is the gamma; the name tends to be used specifically for the case of integer shape parameters. Your thought that other distributions might fit as well as the gamma is a good one.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Glen_b. Now that I am reading further I am actually wondering if there is any benefit to trying to force my data to fit a specified distribution, aside from ease. There are bumps at 12 and 24 oysters (people eating a dozen or two) that are not going to be represented by any distribution, but it's important information. Is it necessary to mix together a couple of distributions for cases like this, or are there ways to use an empirical distribution directly?

Comment: Well, of course you can use empirical distributions directly. (Your title starts with 'fitting', so one assumed that's what you wanted to do.) What do you want to do with the distributions, whether fitted or empirical?

Comment: Sorry for asking something so basic - a lot of this is really new to me. And my question has evolved a lot since I have been researching. Specifically, mc2d seems to ask for an input of serving size. The example in the documentation uses rgamma(shape=X, rate=Y) and I assumed you'd have to put something similarly simple in, although it allows for flexibility in distribution type. I have never needed to use an empirical distribution before, so I actually just don't know how you do it. How would you describe your distribution?

Comment: Perhaps this is also evolving into an R question rather than statistics. I just never realized before today that you were "allowed" to use an empirical distribution..!

Comment: I can't speak to what the package you refer to does or assumes; my response about being able to use empirical distributions was a general one: it is possible to base inference on empirical distributions, since that's the basis of resampling methods - the ecdf is how such as permutation/randomization tests and bootstrap intervals work. In any case your initial question relates simply to smoothing the empirical distribution. An advantage of using parametric distributions for risk assessment (assuming they're reasonable approximations) is they give you some tail - empirical distributions can't

Comment: Thank you - this has been incredibly helpful (as in, changing my whole understanding of how distributions are used, helpful). I am going to do a lot more work on my own and then perhaps I can figure out either how to do what I need on my own, or articulate a less an open-ended question that will get me there.